# Как реализовать пул изменений?

Tags: git, request, стек, pull-request

Проект с непрерывной интеграцией, переход на релизы не возможен. Работает только с консольным гитом. gitLab'a нет.

При каждом пуле на master начинают отрабатывать тесты, которые выполняются до получаса.

Если два разработчика с разницей в 5 минут начинают пушить, то правки первого уйдут успешно, а второй, только после отработки всех тестов, увидит, что есть изменения в цр, которые необходимо запулить, а потом опять: тесты и пуш.

Стали думать как быть, и пришли к идее: все разработчики пушат в цр без тестов. В цр накапливается стек правок. Раз в n минут скрипт применяет первые правки, запускает тесты. Если тесты прошли успешно - применяет их, если нет - откатывает и переходит к следующим в очереди правкам. Естественно каждый блок правок изолирован, в случае отката разработчики будут проинформированы.

Возможно такое реализовать? И если да, тот как? Вряд ли мы первые с этим столкнулись.

P.S. есть отдельный тестовый контур, на котором раз в n часов запускаются тесты. Но тесты рассчитаны на ветку test, которая содержит ~10 веток, из которых только одна должна уйти на бой.

Comment: 1. что такое «цр»? 2. какое отношение к вопросу имеют метки request, stack и pull-request? 3. как у вас ветка (т.е., указатель на коммит) может вообще что-то содержать, не говоря уж про «~10 веток (т.е., указателей на коммит»? 4. вас действительно интересует ответ на вопрос «Возможно такое реализовать?»? такие вопросы, требующие ответа «да/нет», здесь не приветствуются.

Comment: @alexander barakin, 1. цр - центральный репозиторий 2. Отсылка к форкам 3. Ветка = мастер + правки 4. естественно ответ да/ нет ни о чем

Comment: исправить текст вопроса: [edit]

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не думал, что придется уточнять. Вас наверное удовлетворяют ответы вида да/нет?

Comment: @kohhop нельзя оскорблять людей!  если юнит тесты идут больше болучаса, то стоит задуматься о том, что что-то не так

Comment: Вы можете создать список рассылки, в который будут отсылать матчи на ревью, на список посадить бота для тестирования, например как *aiaiai*.

Comment: @ Senior Pomidor кроме unit-тестов есть и фикстурные тесты. И то, что тесты выполняются долго,  это нормально. Есть же НОЧНЫЕ полные тесты, которые выполняются всю ночь. И это нормальная практика.

Comment: 0andriy а можно чучуть поподробнее?